# What's the difference in copyrights between a book and lyrics of a song?

Tags: copyright, music

As far as I understand copyrights, both books and lyrics of a song are protected in the same way. **Are they really?** It's much easier to find whole lyrics of a song than it is to find whole text of a book. And if you reach a book online, it will be on some shady websites only. How come? What's the legal difference?

Comment: It's about damages.  If I illegally distribute a free download of an e-book to (say) 1000 people, it's pretty easy to make a reasonable calculation of the damages of that infringement, based on the market value of the e-book download and based on how many people I distributed to. However, If I illegally distribute only the printed lyrics to a song, though, there's not really a straightforward way to translate the infringement into actual damages, because when customers pay money for a song or a subscription service, they want the music itself; lyrics as text may or may not be included.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no legal difference, really. There may well be a practical difference. It is much easier to steal a wheelbarrow than it is a 20-foot section of 2-foot wide iron conduit. But doing either is theft, and the legalities are pretty much the same.

It is indeed easier to copy a song lyric, or a poem, then the text of a novel, say. But if done without permission, either would be copyright infringement, unless of course an ***exception to copyright***, such as ***fair use*** (in the US) or ***fair dealing*** (in the UK and some other countries) applies. (Or unless the text is out of copyright. One may lawfully copy Shakespeare, for example. Or Mark Twain.)

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that the institutional structures that exist to facilitate getting permission to use a song lyric are much more developed and standardized than the equivalent institutions in the book publishing industry which rarely gets requested for permission to copy a book and negotiates the deals with lawyers drafting licenses on a case by case basis with senior executive involvement when they do.

Comment: Also, song lyrics are more likely to be fair use as copying them has less impact on the market for the recorded or performed song itself.

Comment: Sure on Twain... but you may not legally copy the english translation of a Japanese book written in Heian times, because it [only was translated in 1983...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torikaebaya_Monogatari#Translations_and_adaptations). Copyright in the derivative work for the win!

Comment: @Trish Quiote true. Shakespeare is in the public domain, but *West Side Story* is not.